# Phone number to words based on the dictionary

Tags: ruby, time-limit-exceeded, search

This is the problem:

> Given a 10 digit phone number, you must return all possible words or combination of words from the provided dictionary, that can be mapped back as a whole to the number.
>
> With this we can generate numbers like 1-800-motortruck which is easier to remember then 1-800-6686787825
>
> The phone number mapping to letters is as follows:
>
> ```
> 2 = a b c
> 3 = d e f
> 4 = g h i
> 5 = j k l
> 6 = m n o
> 7 = p q r s
> 8 = t u v
> 9 = w x y z
> ```
>
> The phone numbers will never contain a 0 or 1.  Words have to be at least 3 characters.
>
> To get give you an initial verifiation, the following must be true:
>
> - `6686787825` should return the following list `[["motor", "usual"], ["noun", "struck"], ["nouns", "truck"], ["nouns", "usual"], ["onto", "struck"], "motortruck"] # These words exist in a dictionary file`.
> - The conversion of a 10 digit phone number should be performed within 1000ms.

My solution works but takes longer than 1 sec.
How can I improve my code so execution time will be less than 1 sec?

```
class NumberToWord

  def letter_combinations(digits)
    #return if number not valid
    return [] if digits.nil? || digits.length != 10 || digits.split('').select{|a|(a.to_i == 0 || a.to_i == 1)}.length > 0
    #number to letters mapping
    letters = {"2" => ["a", "b", "c"],"3" => ["d", "e", "f"],"4" => ["g", "h", "i"],"5" => ["j", "k", "l"],"6" => ["m", "n", "o"],"7" => ["p", "q", "r", "s"],"8" => ["t", "u", "v"],"9" => ["w", "x", "y", "z"]}

    # Read dictionary file and hold all values in a array
    dictionary = []
    file_path = "dictionary.txt"
    File.foreach( file_path ) do |word|
      dictionary.push word.chop.to_s.downcase
    end
    # get all letters for numbers in form of array
    keys = digits.chars.map{|digit|letters[digit]}

    results = {}
    total_number = keys.length - 1 # total numbers
    #Loo through all letters and get matching records with dictionary
    for i in (2..total_number)
      first_array = keys[0..i]
      second_array = keys[i + 1..total_number]
      next if first_array.length < 3 || second_array.length < 3
      first_combination = first_array.shift.product(*first_array).map(&:join) # Get product of arrays
      next if first_combination.nil?
      second_combination = second_array.shift.product(*second_array).map(&:join)
      next if second_combination.nil?
      results[i] = [(first_combination & dictionary), (second_combination & dictionary)] # get common values from arrays
    end
    #arrange words like we need as a output
    final_words = []
    results.each do |key, combinataions|
      next if combinataions.first.nil? || combinataions.last.nil?
      combinataions.first.product(combinataions.last).each do |combo_words|
        final_words << combo_words
      end
    end
    # for all numbers
    final_words << (keys.shift.product(*keys).map(&:join) & dictionary).join(", ") # matche with all character
    final_words
  end

end

final_words = NumberToWord.new().letter_combinations("6686787825")
print final_words
```

Comment: Where can we find the dictionary file, if we want to try this out?

Comment: @Flambino can you please let me know any common place where I can put that dictionary, or just give me your email address so  I can send it to you

Comment: this is the file: https://github.com/ansarmirza/assignment/blob/master/db/dictionary.txt

Comment: Please don't edit your main question due to feedback you've received. Feel free to post a  new question with your new code, if you feel like there's more you can improve.

Comment: Sorry that was edit by mistake, I have added the same thing again

Answer (score 4):

I would first start by doing some basic profiling of your application to see where the issues are. This could be as simple as inserting `console.log( (new Date()).valueOf() )` in a few places.

Some things I noticed.

- Is your dictionary file sorted? If not then sort it first. Either way use `bsearch` to locate entries rather han using `&` which is very naive.
- It looks like you are trying every combination of letters but you probably want to use an algorithm that stops if there is no match. For example given `668`, if your dictionary contains no entries starting with `mn` (66) then there is no point in checking `mnt`, `mnu`, mnv` or any of the longer combinations.
- Try to reduce the number of times you copy and modify arrays (`[a..b]` or `shift`)
- This check: `next if first_array.length < 3 || second_array.length < 3` could go before you copy the array (in a slightly modified form). You could just change `for i in (2..total_number)` to `for i in (4..total_number-2)`

Comment: Yes dictionary is sorted

Comment: As I said there are two steps: (1) Do prefix truncation. A 10 digit number has approximately 60,000 possibilities in the form of a branching tree, but if you have no words starting with the first digit, or two, or three you should stop searching that branch. (2) Use `bsearch` to search your dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the optimised solution but still looking for how to write good code, I am now able to get result in 0.4 seconds:

```
require 'date'

class NumberToWordOpt

  def letter_combinations(digits)
    time_start = Time.now()
    #return if number not valid
    return [] if digits.nil? || digits.length != 10 || digits.split('').select{|a|(a.to_i == 0 || a.to_i == 1)}.length > 0
    #number to letters mapping
    letters = {"2" => ["a", "b", "c"],"3" => ["d", "e", "f"],"4" => ["g", "h", "i"],"5" => ["j", "k", "l"],"6" => ["m", "n", "o"],"7" => ["p", "q", "r", "s"],"8" => ["t", "u", "v"],"9" => ["w", "x", "y", "z"]}

    # Read dictionary file and hold all values in a array
    dictionary = {}
    for i in (1..30)
      dictionary[i] = []
    end
    file_path = "dictionary.txt"
    File.foreach( file_path ) do |word|
      dictionary[word.length] << word.chop.to_s.downcase
    end

    keys = digits.chars.map{|digit|letters[digit]}

    results = {}
    total_number = keys.length - 1 # total numbers
    #Loo through all letters and get matching records with dictionary
    for i in (2..total_number - 2)
      first_array = keys[0..i]
      next if first_array.length < 3
      second_array = keys[i + 1..total_number]
      next if second_array.length < 3
      first_combination = first_array.shift.product(*first_array).map(&:join) # Get product of arrays #get_combination(first_array, dictionary)#
      next if first_combination.nil?
      second_combination = second_array.shift.product(*second_array).map(&:join)
      next if second_combination.nil?
      results[i] = [(first_combination & dictionary[i+2]), (second_combination & dictionary[total_number - i +1])] # get common values from arrays
    end
    #arrange words like we need as a output
    final_words = []
    results.each do |key, combinataions|
      next if combinataions.first.nil? || combinataions.last.nil?
      combinataions.first.product(combinataions.last).each do |combo_words|
        final_words << combo_words
      end
    end
    # for all numbers
    final_words << (keys.shift.product(*keys).map(&:join) & dictionary[11]).join(", ") # matche with all character
    time_end = Time.now()
    puts "Time #{time_end.to_f - time_start.to_f}"
    final_words
  end

end

final_words = NumberToWordOpt.new().letter_combinations("6686787825")
print final_words
```